# Python sockets google dns server

Tags: python, sockets, dns

I need my own IP in a small script and in order not to hardcode it, I`ve found a piece of code from here(stackoverflow) that works.

This--

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
    s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
    print(s.getsockname()[0])
```

--
What is not clear for me is why it only works on UDP and not TCP? It has something to do with the google dns server?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have `socket.gethostname()` to learn about your name, no need to try creating a socket.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Google and nothing to do with DNS.

All what this code does is to "connect" a UDP socket to an external IP, so that the OS kernel figures out which local IP address it needs to use in order to reach this external system. This is no real connection, i.e. there is no traffic involved but the OS kernel is only checking routing tables and local interfaces in order to decide which IP address to use as source in case one would actually use the socket to send data.

One could do the same with TCP. But in this case a real TCP connection would be established which means that actual traffic would be exchanged and that the connect would fail if the external system would not be reachable on this port (i.e. no listener, firewall in between etc).

With UDP instead `connect` will not produce any traffic and would fail only if no route to the destination IP address could be determined. This also means that an arbitrary external IP address and port could be used, i.e.  `('1.1.1.1',11)` would work the same as `('8.8.8.8',80)`.